# Adding data to jTable from Database (via Netbeans) no errors, but table disappears

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

somehow in debugging data is fully retrieved and resultModel actually has got column names, and data for rows. Although when compiled and ran in Netbeans after a search, table disappears, no data is shown even column names. Here is the code:

```
private void search(){
    String[][] rowData = new String[0][4];
    String[] columns = {"appointmentid", "fname", "lname", "registration", "make", "model", "engine", "year", "mileage", "type", "date", "time"};
    resultModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,columns);
     add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));

    jTable1 = new JTable(resultModel);

    jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 

     try{
        Model_Customer[] appointment = Controller_ManageCustomer.FindCustomers(Searchtxt.getText());
        resultModel.setRowCount(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < appointment.length; i++)
            resultModel.insertRow(i,new Object[]{appointment[i].GetID(),appointment[i].GetFName(), appointment[i].GetLName(), appointment[i].GetRegistration(), appointment[i].GetMake(), appointment[i].GetModel(), appointment[i].GetEngine(), appointment[i].GetYear(), appointment[i].GetMileage(), appointment[i].GetType(), appointment[i].GetDate(), appointment[i].GetTime()});

    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
  DefaultTableModel resultModel
```

Answer (score 4):

It could just be me...but this looks very suspicious...

```
add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
jTable1 = new JTable(resultModel);
```

Not to mention, you go a build and nice new `DefaultTableModel` but don't actually apply it to anything that is actually on the screen...

Try something more like...

```
resultModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,columns);

 try{
    Model_Customer[] appointment = Controller_ManageCustomer.FindCustomers(Searchtxt.getText());
    resultModel.setRowCount(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < appointment.length; i++) {
        resultModel.insertRow(i,new Object[]{appointment[i].GetID(),appointment[i].GetFName(), appointment[i].GetLName(), appointment[i].GetRegistration(), appointment[i].GetMake(), appointment[i].GetModel(), appointment[i].GetEngine(), appointment[i].GetYear(), appointment[i].GetMileage(), appointment[i].GetType(), appointment[i].GetDate(), appointment[i].GetTime()});
    }

    if (jTable1 == null) {
        jTable1 = new JTable(resultModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
    } else {
        jTable1.setModel(resultModel);
    }

}catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Now, personally, I would simply create the `JTable` and add it to the screen, and leave it alone, and simply change the `TableModel` when ever you wanted to update it's content...

Swing uses a form of the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm, which means it separates the view from the model, meaning that when you want to change what the `JTable` is showing (the view), you simply change the model...

Comment: Thank you, ever so much! deleting the code from the top, and adding if statement helped!

Comment: You really should avoid creating a new instance of the `JTable` if it can be helped

Comment: I'm quite new to Java, and especially to NetBeans deign tools, of which i'm far from even knowing half of design features and netbeans features at all... but i'm learning

Comment: Take the time to learn how to build UI's by hand.  Form designers are great tools, but they need a good understanding of the fundamentals of how to use the UI before they really become useful

Comment: I have used GridBagConstraints before and coded in BlueJ... doing this project in NetBeans as it is easier to design indeed, and not as time consuming. I do really appreciate your help, and taking ur time for giving hints :) Thanks again. My next challenge from tomorrow (as it is 5am right now) is to edit data from this table if it is  possible

Comment: I second @MadProgrammer. If you are using a form designer, very (very) rarely will `new JTable()` be correct to use (or `new()` anything, for that matter). Let the form designer create the components, you just modify their contents/models/etc.

Comment: Also, you'll really want to reconsider your error catching strategy. A `JOptionPane` is really one step above `ex.printStackTrace()`. You should take the time to learn how to log and report your error messages, instead of just telling the user that an error was thrown.